# WCV MaxBufferSize parameter is being ignored

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF client written in Visual Studio 2012 that needs to send a List<> containing several hundred items to its server.  If it sends ten items, it works.  I've had this problem in the past, and I was able to set the MaxBufferSize parameter in the client's config file.  However, I stupidly lost that configuration, and I haven't been able to get it work again.  I'm probably being completely blind, but I don't see what's wrong.

Here's the config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Connection String" value="Dsn=Worthington;uid=anneal;pwd=anneal;Server=localhost;Port=5432" />
    <add key="PropertiesFileList" value="Thermal Properties/TPP Tables.xml" />
    <add key="TuningFileName" value="HeatModelWSC.xml"/>
    <add key="LogPath" value="Logs"/>
    <add key="RunType" value="Console"/>
    <add key="WriteInitialPredictions" value="False"/>
    <add key="WriteRevisedPredictions" value="False"/>
    <add key="WriteFinalTemps" value="False"/>
    <add key="WriteCurrentTemps" value="True"/>
    <add key="WriteTimesToTemp" value="False"/>
    <add key="SuppressInitialPredictions" value="YES"/>
    <add key="SuppressRevisedPredictions" value="YES"/>
    <add key="SuppressOnlinePredictions" value="NO"/>
  </appSettings>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="netTcp"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000"
                 maxBufferSize="20000000"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
                 maxArrayLength="200000000"
                 maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="SimShopService.SimShopService">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="netTcpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="netTcp"
                  contract="SimShopService.ISimShopServiceLib">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexTcpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And, in case it matters, here's the server's config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WriteInitialPredictions" value="False"/>
    <add key="WriteRevisedPredictions" value="False"/>
    <add key="WriteFinalTemps" value="False"/>
    <add key="WriteCurrentTemps" value="True"/>
    <add key="WriteTimesToTemp" value="False"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISimShopServiceLib" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_ISimShopServiceLib"
                 sendTimeout = "00:03:00" />
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_ISimShopServiceLib_Debug" 
                 sendTimeout ="00:30:00"/> 
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint name="NetTcpBinding_ISimShopServiceLib"
                bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_ISimShopServiceLib"
                address="net.tcp://localhost:1235/SimShopService"
                binding="netTcpBinding"
                contract="SimShopServiceReference.ISimShopServiceLib">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint name="NetTcpBinding_ISimShopServiceLib_Debug"
                bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_ISimShopServiceLib_Debug"
                address="net.tcp://localhost:1236/SimShopService"
                binding="netTcpBinding"                
                contract="SimShopServiceReference.ISimShopServiceLib">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please post the complete error details in your thread.
It looks like the file below is more like a client configuration than a server configuration because there is a client section in the configuration. moreover, we could increase the value of the property to the maximum positive INT value since 20KB is too small.
Besides, we had better configure these properties on both the client-side and the server-side.
**Server-side.**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService1.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1" bindingConfiguration="mybinding"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="mybinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="None">
          </security>
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

This is also applicable to the binding used in the client service endpoint.

```
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IService1" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport sslProtocols="None" />
                    </security>
                  <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxDepth="2147483647"/>
                </binding>
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://vabqia969vm:8866/Service1.svc" binding="netTcpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
                name="NetTcpBinding_IService1" />
        </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Please pay attention to apply the configuration by using `bindingConfiguration` property.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.